# Regenerate project.pbxproj file

Tags: swift, xcode, pbxproj

I deleted my pbxproj file in my Xcode project, and I cannot recover it with version control or file system utilities.

Is there a way I can regenerate it from the files I have in my project?  All of my Swift classes are there, as are my XML files.  I just need a pbxproj file so Xcode will read my package.

Comment: The easy way is just to make a new project and migrate your files into it.